# Gaps on top of Div when placing lists in them

Tags: html, css

I'm having this weird issue where when I place a list in a div, it causes a huge gap at the top of the div. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

```
body {
background-color:aliceblue;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#logosearch {
background-color:lightgray;
width:1024px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#nav {
background-color:lightblue;
width:1024px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myvegancookbook/JP899/

Comment: How about posting your code so we can help?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't figure out how to post code. I tried posting a Jfiddle link but it wouldn't let me. Sorry.

Comment: Edit your question and paste the code in, highlight it, and click the code formatting icon on the toolbar

Comment: and the html portion also...

Comment: I was able to post the j fiddle, updated

Comment: see revised answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is impossible to tell, but I would suspect you have some CSS rule placing a top margin or padding on your lists. Have you tried using Firebug or another site analyzer to see what CSS rules are actually being applied?

Edit: yes, looks like you have a margin on the ul... add this to your CSS:

`ul { margin: 0; }`

That's all you need to cancel out margin/padding, you don't need the 0px for each direction like you have in your code.

Also, look into CSS resets, it will help you start at a known baseline so you don't run into issues like this...

Here's your fiddle with the change made: http://jsfiddle.net/JP899/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can add at the begin of your css file some rules to reset all values and then begin to  write your own paddings or margins. You can use something like:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```